# ASP.Net Timeout issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, iis, web

I developed a medium sized asp.net website that accepts several hundred pdf documents a day.  I have a very simple insert SP that inserts the documents into an Image field in SQL Server 2008 R2.

A few times a week I am starting to have an issue where my website seems to be timing out on this insert.  Its very strange cause my drop down lists still load and authentication still works.    Most of the time I can recycle the application pool or restart IIS and that fixes everything.

That is a very simplified version of course but thats the long and short of it.  Has anyone else had an issue like this ??

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you closing the connections properly?

Comment: I believe so, also, if I werent then nothing would be working I assume..  I can still get to other areas of the website just fine. Its only this one area that times out.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the maximum pool size:-

If this doesn't work, set the command timeout to 0. Please send us the exactly error message if the two above solutions don't work